# Run command when beginning writing and 4 seconds after stop writing

Tags: c#, vb.net, autohotkey

I need to run a program every time I start writing and again 4 seconds after I stop writing.

How to do this?

I've tryied with autohotkey with no luck..

Comment: What are you writing in?

Comment: I have RSI (Repetitive Strain Injury). I'm trying to integrate eViacam (a Camera-Mouse software) and a DwellClicker. The problem is that the Dwell Clicker keep clicking while I'm writing. So i want to use PsSuspend to pause it every time i start writing, and resume when I finish writing :)

Comment: https://windows-dwell-clicker.googlecode.com/files/DwellClicker.exe

Comment: http://eviacam.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I already have a script to integrate eViacam with www.workrave.org (In case someone has also RSI and needs it, I can share it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested script but should work with some tweaking, I don't think the psTools command is correct and I'm not going to install all these programs to test it for you. I'll be happy to help further if you need assistance from here.

AutoHotkey:

```
startDwellClicker() {
    Input, key, V L1, {space}.{esc}.{shift}.{enter}.{tab}.{Ctrl} ;Waits for Anykey to be pressed
    Run, pssuspend "-r \\%A_ComputerName% dwellclicker.exe" ;Resume DwellClicker
    pauseDwellClicker()
}

pauseDwellClicker() {
    Loop {
        Input, key, V L1 T4 
        if (ErrorLevel = "Timeout") ;Waits for 4 second Time Out
            Break
    }
    Run, pssuspend "\\%A_ComputerName% dwellclicker.exe" ;Pause DwellClicker
    startDwellClicker()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Working solution :)

Comment: @CuchoAv  please mark this a answered. I believe it's an option on the upper left side of the Answer, this option only appears for the poster.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what ps is or RSI, but I know that AutoHotkey was made for you.

```
#persistent

waitTime := 4   ; seconds

isWriting := false
loop {
    input, anyKey, V L1 M I T%waitTime%
    if(errorLevel=="Timeout") {
        if(isWriting) {
            goSub stoppedWriting
            isWriting := false
        }
    } else {
        if(!isWriting) {
            goSub startedWriting
            isWriting := true
        }
    }
}

return

startedWriting:
    send START
return

stoppedWriting:
    send STOP
return
```

You have to make use of the `Input` command and set its timeout time to whatever you want, in the example above I set it to 4 seconds. Please see [Input](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Input.htm) for details on the available options for this command.

Edit. I misinterpreted ahkcoder's answer, his will do

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
Didn't try the other codes, but seems very similar to what finally I did.
I've used autohotkey :)

BTW: RSI is basically.. a big pain in hand, legs, shoulders, fingers because of computer :(... hehe

This is the working code:

```
Loop{
  Input, SingleKey, L1 V I B, {F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Del}{BS}{WheelUp}{WheelDown}



  MouseGetPos,xpos,ypos

  stop:=0
  Run "D:\RSI\DesactivaDwell.vbs"
  While !stop {
    wait:=2500
    While wait>0{
    ;If ANY Key is pressed again, we set wait=4000. Input works as Sleep for 100ms ( Parameter T0.1)
    Input,SingleKey, L1 V I B T0.5, {F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Del}{BS}{WheelDown}{WheelUp}{RButton}
    If ErrorLevel=Timeout 
          wait-=500
    Else
    wait:=2500
    }

    Sleep,1000
    Run "D:\RSI\ActivaDwell.vbs"

    stop:=1
  }
}
```